# How do i change the format of I/O?

Tags: c, algorithm, input

Input format: The first line of input gives the number the input strings (without spaces and of maximum 100 length
and in lowercase). Then there is following n lines, each containing a string.

Output format: N lines of output, each line has either YES or NO following by newline. (YES if string is a magic square palindrome otherwise NO)

Sample Input:
4

satorarepotenetoperarotas

aba

abba

abcabacba

Sample Output:

YES

NO

YES

NO

So i have written the following code.But in my program the output gets displayed immediately after the input and it takes only one input at a time.

PS:If you have any suggestions on how to make the code more efficient,please add them in your answer.Thanks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{   int num_input,l;
    scanf("%d",&num_input);
    for(l=0;l<num_input;l++)
    {
    char str[100];
    char i = 0;
    int sq,j,k;
    scanf("%s", str);
    while(str[i]!='\0')
    {
        ++i;

    }

    sq = sqrt(i);
    if(i== sq*sq)
    {
    if(i%2==0)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=i/2;j++)
        {
            if((str[j]==str[i-j-1])&&(str[j+sq]==str[i-j-sq-1]))
            {
                if(j==i/2)
                {
                    printf("YES\n");
                }           
            }
            else
            {   if(j==i/2)
                {
                        printf("NO\n");
            }
            }
        }
    }

    if(i%2!=0)
    {
        for(k=0;k<=i/2;k++)
        {
            if((str[k]==str[i-k-1])&&(str[k+sq]==str[i-k-sq-1]))

                {   if(k==i/2)
                {
                    printf("YES\n");    
                }}

            else
                {if(j==i/2)
                {
                printf("NO\n");
                }}

        }
    }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("NO\n");
    }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: If you don't want to interleave inputs and outputs, don't put them both in the same loop.

Comment: A good first step would be to [indent](http://mrbool.com/importance-of-code-indentation/29079) your code properly. Then a reader (and the writer, too!) will just know which if is in which loop, instead of guessing or spending attention on it every time.

Comment: read strings input first, store in an array. Then process inputs strings and display results.

Comment: Sorry for the indentation.I am new to programming

Comment: You will need a list (read: array) of all relevant information about each line in order to first read all lines and then output the result for each line. A possible solution with small changes of your code would be an array of integer values, where you store a `0` for each "NO" and a `1` for each "YES". Assign the values in place of your current output statements. Then, create a new loop where you iterate the array and print YES or NO depending on the integer value.

Comment: ... and that's why it's useful for the program input to start with the number of strings that should be expected.  That way, you know how many elements such an array will need.

Comment: @grek40 The output I understand.Can you specify how to implement the input?

Comment: This looks like it's for a programming competition or automated evaluation of some sort. In that case, the way you are giving output now is all right. In the actual evaluation the input will be redirected from a file and output will be redirected to a file. *You do not have to worry about input and output alternating*

Comment: Yes...Sort of...Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of 'mixed' output and input is caused by the fact, that you take one string per calculation. If you want to scan the whole input, then display the output, you should... do exactly that. Simple approach how to do it, given that you know how many strings will be typed:

After you scan the number of strings with `int num_input; scanf("%d",&num_input);`, you can create a two-dimensional array of characters sized as `[num_input][max_str_length]`. From your code, I assume that maximal length of each individual string is 100 (given `char str[100];`).

Then, in a `for` loop, that loops `num_input` times, you should scan all your strings and place them in the proper places in your 2D array. This way, your input is stored and ready to be checked by an algorithm. I would encourage you to, instead of writing plain algorith inside of `main` function, create a function that will take an array and it's size as arguments and return `true` or `1` when given array contains a string that is a "magic square palindrome" or return `false` / `0` when it's not. If you do that, you can just loop `num_input` times again and call your function on currently checked array. Each time the fucntion returns `true`, you output "YES", otherwise "NO"/

If you don't know anything about 2D arrays and/or making functions yourself, I encourage you to either buy a good C book, or simple google some tutorials, because that stuff is pretty basic and fairly easy to understand.